# Issue with the iframe Height just on Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, iframe, height

I got a problem with the iframe height just on Chrome. All anothers common browsers like IE, Opera, Safari, and FF works fine.

`<iframe runat="server" id="ifTest" name="ifTest" frameborder="0" height="790px"
                            width="960px" style="position:inherit;"></iframe>`

in all browsers this works fine, but in Chrome, appears a big white space at the bottom of the page, after the footer. If I drop the Height in the iframe, the iframe will be tiny but without the big white space at the bottom of the page after the footer.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: I think the `height` and `width` properties expressed as pixels without the need for "px" (`width="960"` instead of `width="960px"`). The "px" could be causing some quirkiness in Chrome. Also, as mentioned by @Warface, try setting the height and width using CSS (inline `style="position:inherit; width: 960px; height: 790px"`).

Comment: I've tried with your code and adding Google as loading page and it's working fine on Chrome for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
iframe#ifTest{
   width:960px;
   height:790px;
}
```

and remove the width and height from the iframe tag

Answer (score 0):

But the iframe call a foreign page. I don't have this page in my solution. I tried some javascript like

`function resizeFrame(f) {
                    f.style.height = f.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
                }`

Answer (score 0):

It helps in my case ( working in **Chrome** & **Moz.Firefox** ):

```
iframe {
    height:100vh; // without it doesn't works
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

<iframe frameborder="0" name="iframe_article"></iframe>
```